# Grafana sometimes can't resolve prometheus hostname

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

*Scenario*

I deploy grafana and prometheus onto EKS cluster (AWS K8s service).

If I use prometheus service's fqdn (prometheus-server.monitoring.svc.cluster.local) as the data source, grafana sometimes fail to load the data like the image below. If I refresh the page several times and if I'm lucky, I'll get all the panels to display correctly.

[image]

logging out the grafana pod gives

```
http: proxy error: dial tcp: lookup prometheus-server.monitoring.svc.cluster.local: no such host
```

If I use prometheus service's cluster IP address instead of the fqdn, everything works just fine.

*Question*

What's wrong with using prometheus service's fqdn?

Comment: Could you prove that the network is working fine?